# Yii 2. How to change text on button Reset

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Have a website and form to search. Dont know where to find file, where I can change text on my "Reset" button. For example change to "Erase all".

Now i have this button with text:"Reset"
I tried to search in "yii\widgets\ActiveForm" and "kartik\select2\Select2" files.
But could not find.

```
    <?php
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\search\ProductSearch */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */      ?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="gadget-search">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => ['index'],
            'method' => 'get',
            'options' => [
                'data-pjax' => true,
                'id' => 'wow',
                'class' => 'form-inline',
            ],
        ]); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Reset'), Url::toRoute([]), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean  the translated title  text  or the simple title" Reset" or Others ?

Comment: I think you are asking where to find the template to change the text on the reset button. But I can't be sure. Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Yes, i want to edit text on 'Reset' button to some other text, for example: "Erase all"

Comment: It can be any text, even to other language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Yii::t('app', 'Reset')` is the text outputted on the reset button. you can replace it directly:

```
<?= Html::a("Erase all", Url::toRoute([]), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
```

but that will break you translation. To change it properly you'll need to check the i18n application component configs to see to which file that `app` [category](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#t()-detail) is pointing. If it was built following [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#2-configure-one-or-multiple-message-sources) then it may look like this:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

That `app.php` file hosted under `@app/messages` should return an array. Find the `Reset` key there and change its text or alternatively add `Erase all` as a new key with its equivalent translation text in all related languages files then call it using `Yii::t('app', 'Erase all')`.

Comment: Thank u! I found it in 'common' -> 'messages'